# How to spell the contraction of "might as well"

Tags: contractions

I often say a word that sounds like "mares-well", as a contraction of "might as well". E.g. if someone said "shall I throw away this bread" I might say "you might as well, it's totally mouldy", except I'd pronounce "might as well" as something like "mares-well" (where 'mare' is pronounced like the 'mare' in 'nightmare').

Is there a written form of this sound? If so, how do I spell it?

Comment: It this contraction a common one in your community?

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, I think it's fairly common. I fully expected it to be a regional thing, but I would be slightly surprised if another English person didn't understand it in context.

Comment: I am not familiar with it, (I guess it is used only in spoken language ) anyway other common contractions  with might are 'might've' and 'mightn't' with no big differences in spelling.

Comment: I assume that you're not American, so "mares-well" has no actual "r" in it.

Comment: @PeterShor you assume correctly - are you saying that the answer to my question is simply "maes-well"? Or are you just saying that you wouldn't expect me to pronounce it with the 'r' in it?

Comment: DOWN VOTER: if you explain why, I can ask better questions in the future.

Comment: I think I know what you mean - the 't' is dropped and the 'as' is contracted - I'd probably write it as "migh's'well"

Comment: ^ sorry I meant "migh'swell" (only one apostrophe). It's reasonably pronunciation-neutral.

Comment: Since that's a phoneme that only appears in British English, and the primary way of spelling it is with an "r", if you want something that Brits will know how to pronounce perfectly and won't totally confuse Americans, I think you're out of luck. @JHCL's suggestion of "migh'swell" is a good compromise.

Comment: Oh I've just had the thought (having said it aloud) that 'mares-well' may actually be a contraction of 'may as well'.

Comment: I pronounce it frequently as [ma:ʸs'wɛw], under fæspicrulz. I'm rhotic, but a non-rhotic listener might well hear that long a: as /ar/ or /ær/ (the vowel is rather fronted). And _may as well_ is another possibility, too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's predicated on a misconception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are mis-hearing ["may as well"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/may-as-well-and-might-as-well) and interpreting it as "might as well -

> We can use may as well and might as well for making suggestions. We can use them to say what we think is the easiest or most logical course of action when we cannot see a better alternative. They are both fairly informal. Might as well is more common than may as well
>
> *dictionary.cambridge.org*

When these words are said quickly and rolled together it is easy to see how they might be heard as "mares well", in my opinion.

Comment: Not just mis-hearing, but mis-saying too. I think you've probably got it correct though, I was assuming there was written contraction and didn't really consider that it might just be a spoken thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I once saw this contraction written as part of character dialogue - I.e. to display the character’s dialect - as ‘Moswell’, ‘Mosswell’, or something very similar.
I will invent an example.

“I say, Erik, the scouts are reporting an enemy camp setting up near the river, about six miles west.”
Erik considered this new information for all of five seconds before he grunted, stood up, and hefted his war-axe.
“Moswell go over and give ‘em a kickin’ then, eh?”

I would suggest that in American English the verbal contraction of ‘may as well’ becomes ‘Mayswell’, where as ‘might as well’ is barely contracted - it’s just said quickly and sounds like ‘Midaswell’. In British English, the contraction is still ‘Mayswell’, although some dialects, particularly northern, definitely have a vowel pronunciation that sounds closer to ‘Mehswell’. In British English, the R in the word ‘Mare’ is rarely pronounced. Imagine pronouncing ‘Air’ without the R sound at the end, and you’ve got it. ‘Maiswell?’
In British English, ‘might as well’ becomes ‘my’aswell’, with the apostrophe after the Y signifying the staccato stop where the T would normally go. It is simply missing.

Comment: Great first post, but it would benefit from a linked source being added. Take the tiem to enjoy the [tour] and (when you have plenty of spare time) read-up in teh [help] about how we work. Welcome to EL&U.